# How does require('atom') work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, atom-editor

Atom exposes some global APIs that you can access from `require('atom')`

How does this functionally work? Atom packages don't explicitly have atom as a dependency, yet they can still do this. Moreover, how can I do this in my own Electron application with my own global package?

Comment: In what context, and what packages are you requiring in your `package.json` file?

Comment: `node_modules` can be [found in any parent directory](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

Comment: As mentioned, this is in packages for the text editor Atom.

Comment: @jonathan yes, but if atom does provide it normally like this, what is the directory structure it uses that can be replicated in other Electron applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through and analyzed Atom's source myself to determine how this happens, and this is what I've come up with.

Atom packages are required using the [normal node require](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/e8693f45c902f1b371aae15ec01271d841bbc94e/src/package.coffee#L439). However, according to the [apm](https://github.com/atom/apm) readme:

> The other major difference is that Atom packages are installed to
>   ~/.atom/packages instead of a local node_modules folder...

So the `require('atom')` package isn't retrieved from a parent `node_modules` directory like normal node modules. Instead, Atom overrides the module loader to change the behavior a bit.

More specifically, they override [`Module._resolveFilename`](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/e8693f45c902f1b371aae15ec01271d841bbc94e/src/module-cache.coffee#L270-L273) like so:

```coffeescript
Module = require 'module'

Module._resolveFilename = (relativePath, parentModule) ->
  resolvedPath = resolveModulePath(relativePath, parentModule)
  resolvedPath ?= resolveFilePath(relativePath, parentModule)
  resolvedPath ? originalResolveFilename(relativePath, parentModule)
```

It attempts to resolve the path of a module with its own module cache logic before defaulting to normal behavior. This is done for a couple reasons that I can tell.

1. It lets them hardcode the path of builtin modules like `'atom'`, even though the normal behavior would never have found it.
2. It prevents loading package dependencies twice when packages have the same dependency with compatible versions. If packageA loads lodash@4.x.x and later packageB attempts to load lodash@>=3, then Atom steps in and gives packageB the lodash that packageA loaded.